# Convert all rows of a Pandas dataframe column to comma-separated values with each value in single quote

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe similar to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns=['Col'])

df

Col
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
```

I am trying to convert all rows of this column to a comma-separated string with each value in single quotes, like below:

```
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
```

I have tried the following with several different combinations, but this is the closest I got:

```
s = df['Col'].str.cat(sep="', '")
s
"a', 'b', 'c', 'd"
```

I think that the end result should be:

```
"'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'"
```

Comment: How about `"'" + df.Col1.str.cat(sep="','") + "'"`?

Comment: Thank you, It works, would you like to add your comment as an answer for me to accept?

Comment: great it worked. I think BEN_YO has similar in answer, may be you can accept that one. `Happy Coding.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix will be

```
"'" + df['Col1'].str.cat(sep="', '") + "'"
"'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'"
```

Comment: Why 'Col1' (in contrast to 'Col')?

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is adding each element with an extra quote and then use the default `.join`;

```
', '.join([f"'{i}'" for i in df['Col1']])
```

---

```
"'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = df['Col'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns=['Col1'])

values = df['Col1'].to_list()
with_quotes = ["'"+x+"'" for x in values]
','.join(with_quotes)
```

Output:

`"'a','b','c','d'"`